# PHP IF ELSE condition and Foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I have a small issue trying to compare data from 3 arrays, one of them is the source and the other 2 are the conditions.

the scenario is the next:

```
$array1 = array('code' => '123', 'code' => '124', 'code' => '125', 'code' => '126', 'code' => '127');
$array2 = array(
    array('code1' => '123', 'country' => 'US', 'listed' => '0'), 
    array('code1' => '124', 'country' => 'US', 'listed' => '1'),
    array('code1' => '125', 'country' => 'US', 'listed' => '1')
);
$array3 = array(
    array('code2' => '123', 'country' => 'US', 'listed' => '1'),
    array('code2' => '126', 'country' => 'US', 'listed' => '0'),
    array('code2' => '127', 'country' => 'US', 'listed' => '1')
);

$final = array_merge($array1,$array2,$array3);

foreach ($final as $f) {
    if ($f['code'] == $f['code1']) {
        if ($f['listed'] > 0) {
            $finalListed = $f['listed'];
        }
    } elseif ($f['code'] == $f['code2']) {
        if ($f['listed'] > 0) {
            $finalListed = $f['listed'];
        }
    }

    $newFinalArray = array(
        'code' = $finalCode,
        'listed' = $finalListed,
        'country' = $finalCountry
    );
}
```

So what i need is to check first if the code from `$array1` exist in `$array2` and if if the code from `$array2` is listed if not check on `$array3` and so on.

So if the code exist on `$array2` and listed is 1 update database with this values if not check `$array3` if exist and listed is 1 update with the values if not update the values from `$array2`

The idea is that `$array2` is from 1 site and `$array3` is from another, so, if is not in 1 is the second if are in both keek from `$array2`

The problem is that i cannot get it sort, i have tried `array_combine` but this combines only 2 arrays and the parameters need to be exactly.
With array merge i get the 3 arrays into one, then on foreach and on apply if conditions it say that the variable is undefined.

Comment: What about in_array()? http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: you mean find each code in_array $array2 and $array3 ?, how can i do the foreach for the 3 arrays ?

Comment: ehm, something like foreach($array1 as $key => $code) { if(in_array($code, $array2){ echo 'It's in the array!'; }

Comment: Well, $array2 is a multidimensional array, same as $array1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I see a lots of issue in the way arrays are declared by you

Ex -

```
$array1 = array('code' = > '123', 'code' = > '124', 'code' = > '125', 'code' = > '126', 'code' = > '127');
```

is nothing but

```
$array1 = array('code' => '127'); //because of same index it will only consider the last value
```

However I have modified your arrays and tried to prepare a solution which might be useful for you. Check it once below.

```
<?php
$array1 = array('123', '124', '125', '126', '127');
$array2 = array(array('code' => '123', 'country' => 'US', 'listed' => '0'),     array('code' => '124', 'country' => 'US', 'listed' => '1'), array('code' => '125', 'country' => 'US', 'listed' => '1'));
$array3 = array(array('code' => '123', 'country' => 'US', 'listed' => '1'), array('code' => '126', 'country' => 'US', 'listed' => '0'), array('code' => '127', 'country' => 'US', 'listed' => '1'));

function compareSitesAndUpdate($array1, $array2, $array3) {
    foreach($array1 as $code) {
    if(isCodeExistsInArray($code,$array2)) {
       echo $code . ' is in array2 and listed <br />';
    }
    else { // ;( Not in Array2 check in Array3
      echo $code . ' not listed in array2 - checking in array3 <br />';
      if(isCodeExistsInArray($code,$array3)) {
         echo $code . ' is in array3 and listed <br />';
      }
      else {
        echo $code . ' not listed in array3 also - do whatever you want to do <br />';
      }
    } 
    }
}

//Note $earray is always expected to be in the format of $array2/$array3
//And key of $array2 and $array3 should always be 'code' - Not necessary to change the keys are they are two diff arrays
function isCodeExistsInArray($ecode, $earray) {
    foreach($earray as $code_array) {
    if($ecode == $code_array['code']) { //code match found - now check if it is listed
       if($code_array['listed'] == 1) { //Got what we need - return TRUE and Break
        return TRUE;
       }
        }
    }

    return FALSE; //any other case return False;
}

compareSitesAndUpdate($array1, $array2, $array3);
?>
```

Comment: you;re right, i missed to remove the multidimensional array from first array, it works but my question now is how can i pass the country variable from array1 and array2 to the compareSitesAndUpdate function ?

Comment: in isCodeExistsInArray() function you can return the array instead of true and use it. If may declare a global variable and assign $code_array to it and use it if you are using procedural PHP. If you are using OOPS and Classed, you can have a class variable defined and update its value with $code_array and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this:

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $code){
 if(in_array($code, $array2) {
  echo 'Value is in the array! :D ';
 } 
 else {
  if(in_array($code, $array3) {
    echo 'Value is in array3! :D';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have the same key for codes in both arrays: `$array2` and `$array3`, i.e.:

```
$array1 = array(
    '123', 
    '124', 
    '125', 
    '126', 
    '127'
);

$array2 = array(
    array('code' => '123', 'country' => 'US', 'listed' => '0'),
    array('code' => '124', 'country' => 'US', 'listed' => '1'),
    array('code' => '125', 'country' => 'US', 'listed' => '1')
);

$array3 = array(
    array('code' => '123', 'country' => 'US', 'listed' => '1'),
    array('code' => '126', 'country' => 'US', 'listed' => '0'),
    array('code' => '127', 'country' => 'US', 'listed' => '1')
);
```

Then:

```
$newFinalArray = array_filter(array_merge($array2, $array3), function($el){
    if($el['listed'] > 0 && in_array($el['code'], $GLOBALS['array1'])) {
        return true;
    }
});
```